# How to reverse this json

Tags: php, sql, json

I have a problem about array reversing. I tried array_reverse(...,true) But it is not working. May be the place that i applied is wrong. So i already attached my php code and json result below. Plz help me to reverse this json.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT story_id,story_name,story_author,story_cover_link FROM short_story 
 WHERE parent=0");

// parent categories node
$categories = array("Categories" => array());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
     $story_id = $row['story_id'];

     $ssql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT story_id,chapter_name,chapter_link FROM short_story WHERE  parent='$story_id'");

     // single category node
     $category = array(); // temp array
     $category["story_id"] = $row["story_id"];
     $category["story_name"] = $row["story_name"];
     $category["story_author"] = $row["story_author"];
     $category["story_cover_link"] = $row["story_cover_link"];
     $category["chapters"] = array(); // subcategories again an array

     while ($srow = mysqli_fetch_array($ssql,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
         {
         $subcat = array(); // temp array
         $subcat["story_id"] = $srow['story_id'];
         $subcat["chapter_name"] = $srow['chapter_name'];
         $subcat["chapter_link"] = $srow['chapter_link'];
         // pushing sub category into subcategories node

         array_push($category["chapters"], $subcat);
     }

     // pushing sinlge category into parent
     array_push($categories["Categories"], $category);
 }

 echo json_encode($categories);
```

This is resultant json. What i want is, i want to reverse this. After reversion

```
{
"Categories": [{
    "story_id": "1",
    "story_name": "Nethuu",
    "story_author": "Gimhani Thennakon",
    "story_cover_link": "http:\/\/appzoneproduction.xyz\/sinhala_novels\/Cover\/sonduru_nawodaya.jpg",
    "chapters": [{
        "story_id": "7",
        "chapter_name": "Nethu - 1",
        "chapter_link": "http:\/\/appzoneproduction.xyz\/sinhala_novels\/Novel\/gal%20kanda%20walawwa.pdf"
    }, {
        "story_id": "8",
        "chapter_name": "Nethu - 2",
        "chapter_link": "http:\/\/appzoneproduction.xyz\/sinhala_novels\/Novel\/gal%20kanda%20walawwa.pdf"
    }, {
        "story_id": "9",
        "chapter_name": "Nethu - 3",
        "chapter_link": "http:\/\/appzoneproduction.xyz\/sinhala_novels\/Novel\/gal%20kanda%20walawwa.pdf"
    }]
}, {
    "story_id": "2",
    "story_name": "Sewwandi",
    "story_author": "Gayana S Lakmali",
    "story_cover_link": "http:\/\/appzoneproduction.xyz\/sinhala_novels\/Cover\/gal%20kanda%20walawwa.jpg",
    "chapters": [{
        "story_id": "10",
        "chapter_name": "Sewwandi - 1",
        "chapter_link": "http:\/\/appzoneproduction.xyz\/sinhala_novels\/Novel\/gal%20kanda%20walawwa.pdf"
    }, {
        "story_id": "11",
        "chapter_name": "Sewwandi - 2",
        "chapter_link": "http:\/\/appzoneproduction.xyz\/sinhala_novels\/Novel\/gal%20kanda%20walawwa.pdf"
    }]
}]
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: What you means about reverse ? do you want to `"story_id": "2"` first index of json ?

Comment: yes. I want id index as 2,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are looking for is to just have ID's go descending instead of ascending, you dont need to revise the whole array. You could just query the db to deliver data in that order and just run through it as you already do.

Change this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT story_id,story_name,story_author,story_cover_link FROM short_story 
 WHERE parent=0");
```

To this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT story_id,story_name,story_author,story_cover_link FROM short_story 
 WHERE parent=0 ORDER BY story_id DESC");
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ice76 is correct, but there is an alternative solution that should eliminate the need for changing the query and have a slight performance boost.  If you're trying to add the `Categories` in reverse order, just use [array_unshift()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) instead of array_push():

```
// pushing sinlge category into parent
array_unshift($categories["Categories"], $category);
```

If you want to do the same with the `chapters`:

```
// pushing sub category into subcategories node
array_unshift($category["chapters"], $subcat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_reverse`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) basic function. this reverse your array.

easy and fast like this:

```
$categories['Categories'] = array_reverse($categories['Categories']);
echo json_encode($categories);
```